# save location vector of an object

Tags: python, scripting

i like to measure the distance a object has traveled over time. But i fail already at saving the current vector.
The result for test and location are always (except first frame change where test = 
At any other frame change test and location show equal results. Where is my mistake?

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from math import *
test = Vector((0,0,0))
def my_handler(scene):
    global test
    print('test:'+str(test))
    location = bpy.data.objects['cube1'].location
    print(location)
    test = location

for i in range(len(bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post)):
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.pop()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

An example "print" result:
test:

test:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print statement worked fine for me. My approach would be to collect the positions in a list and iterate at the last frame over the list to determine the length.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from math import *

test = Vector((0,0,0))
locations = [] # list to hold all locations between start and end frame

def my_handler(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == scene.frame_start:
        locations.clear()
    if scene.frame_current == scene.frame_end:
        total_len = 0
        for i in range(len(locations)-1):
            d = locations[i] - locations[i+1]
            total_len += d.length
        print("length %f" % total_len )

    location = bpy.data.objects['cube1'].location
    locations.append(Vector(location))
    #print(location)
    #print(locations)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem while trying to search for the location of a sphere. I fixed it by multiplying the location by the world matrix, i.e. :

```
location = bpy.data.objects['cube1'].matrix_world * bpy.data.objects['cube1'].location
```

Maybe it will work for you too.

Comment: i'll try it. But i never understand what the matrix_world or bone is! Is there anything more than the explanation from blender api?

Comment: @user2488 I don't know about the bone as I'm fairly new to Blender and animation in general, but you can consider that there are several coordinate systems in a scene: for ex, imagine you are sitting in a train; in reference to the train, you are still: your position is constant in the object coordinate system of the train; but compared to the ground, you are moving: your "world" coordinates change according to the speed/etc of the train. In this example, the world matrix transform the coordinates so that you know your position compared to the ground.

Comment: Okay i already understood this. But i don' know what values the single elements of the matrix are representing. I know there are 3 elements for scale, 3 elements for location. But for what are the other 10 for? (4 rotation quat?). Is there any page that is explaining that elements?

Comment: Actually this is not as simple. The first 3 columns represent the 3 basis vectors of the new coordinate system in the old, and the last column represents its origin. I found this [article](http://mabulous.com/understanding-and-interpreting-the-homogeneous-transformation-matrix-in-3d-space). The matrix is the result of rotation/translation/scaling applied in the desired order. You can deduce the translation because it's the same as the origin, but the scale coefficients can be affected by rotation. Better examples [here](http://www.codinglabs.net/article_world_view_projection_matrix.aspx)